# Java Swing: 'java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved' error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jbutton

I have been trying to create a 'catch me if you can' game: when I start it, it randomly chooses where to allocate a 'click me' button. I am not supposed to be able to click the button, the text should be re-assigned to another button before I am able to do that.

It works for a while but then it throws the following error: "java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved".

I have been trying to fix the problem with removeListener() method but I don't seem to be able to find a solution. Any comments?

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    //Panels
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    // Buttons
    private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
    private JButton theChosenButton = new JButton();
    // other
    private int random = 0; 

    public Game() {
        this.setTitle("Catch me if you can");
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        // creates buttons
        for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton();
            mainPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        // Add everything to frame
        this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    // generates random number between 1 and 9 to be used 
    public int clickMeGenerator(){
        random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        return random;
    }

    // randomly assigns clickMeGenerator to a button
    // add mouseMoved listener to the chosen button
    public void assign(){
        int randomButton = this.clickMeGenerator();
        theChosenButton = buttons[randomButton];
        theChosenButton.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseHover());
        theChosenButton.setText("Click me");    
    }
    public void removeListener() {
            theChosenButton.removeMouseMotionListener(new MouseHover());
        //}
    }

    // inner class
    class MouseHover implements MouseMotionListener {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            theChosenButton.setText("");
            Game.this.assign();

        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    }

} // end of class
```

Test class:

```
public class GameTest {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Game myGame = new Game();
        myGame.assign();
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Suggestions: (1) use the `mouseEntered` event of `MouseListener` rather than `mouseMoved` of `MouseMotionListener`.  (2) Register the listener on all the buttons at the same time.  Have it test (on mouse entry) whether the event source is the currently-selected button, and in that case only move the label.  (3) Modify your `assign()` method to ensure that it does not re-select the currently chosen button.

Comment: As a separate, but important, matter, construct your GUI and perform the initial button assignment *on the event dispatch thread*, by means of `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`.  Swing is not thread safe.

Comment: For clarity, the actual error is `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError` .. `at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:337)`

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarity, the "actual" error is ...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:337)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:337)
```

So looking through the code...

```
  public void assign() {
    int randomButton = this.clickMeGenerator();
    theChosenButton = buttons[randomButton];
    theChosenButton.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseHover());
    theChosenButton.setText("Click me");
  }
```

You are repeatedly add a new `MouseMotionListener` to you buttons, over and over again, and...

```
  public void removeListener() {
    theChosenButton.removeMouseMotionListener(new MouseHover());
    //}
  }
```

is pointless, as you're trying to remove a new instance of `MouseHover` from the button, but it will never have been applied in the first place.

The first thing I would do is create an instance of `MouseHover` as an instance field in `Game`

```
 private MouseHover mouseHover = new MouseHover();
```

and use it when calling `addMouseMotionListener` and `removeMouseMotionListener`.

I would then, remove the listener from the "currently" active button before adding it to the next one.

Personally, I would do this in the `assign` method

```
public void assign() {
  int randomButton = this.clickMeGenerator();
  if (theChosenButton != null) {
    theChosenButton.removeMouseMotionListener(mouseHover);
  }
  theChosenButton = buttons[randomButton];
  theChosenButton.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHover);
  theChosenButton.setText("Click me");
}
```

I would also ensure that `assign` is called from within the Event Dispatching Thread when the class is first created, as the UI has been realised by the end of the constructor of `Game`, meaning the first call to `assign` is outside of the context of the EDT, which is not recommended.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Game myGame = new Game();
      myGame.assign();
    }
  });
}
```